# Jquery Navigation Toggle going too far down the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

URL: http://zestofsuccess.com/finch/

When the menu icon in the top right hand corner is clicked, the navigation opens but it slides too far down the page. Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the Jquery I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

/* prepend menu icon */
$('#top-menu-nav').prepend('<div id="menu-icon"></div>');

/* toggle nav */
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $("#top-menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: it would be great if fiddle available

Comment: it works in my browser. google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a fixed width on `ul#top-menu`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CSS issue.
Change `margin-top` on `ul#top-menu` from 60px to 10px;

Also, `#main-header` needs a fixed height. I gave it 75px and that removed the bounce.

Comment: changed the CSS to the following: ul#top-menu {margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 30px;}
#top-menu li {margin-top: 50px} But issue remains the same (the menu jumps far lower than it needs to when it toggles open). It bounces back up but I'd like to have it only lower to where it needs to.

Comment: Also tried taking out the top margin, but it always extends further down when opened.

Comment: #main-header needs a fixed height.

Comment: Okay, now I see your dilemma. Try designing the site so that the navigation itself has a white background. That way, it doesn't have to "push" another element. What's happening is, the main-header doesn't have a fixed height, so I'm thinking jQuery doesn't know exactly how to handle it.

Comment: I see why it cannot have a fixed height, as it needs to be fluid as the page crunches for mobile, and the navigation becomes block and not inline.

Comment: setting a fixed width for #top-menu seemed to work. I have to check browser compatibility though. Thank for your help!